# Inserting a two diminsionale array in database from multiple dynamic fields - Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, input, field

Using Laravel I created a form where dynamically input fields can be added and remove using jQuery.

I am now trying to insert the data into the database, there I encounter a problem. My database exists of two tables; Tasks and issues.
The 'issue' table is linked to the tasks table bij task_id. This task_id should be also sent to the database but I can't get it, wright. See my code below.

Thanks for the help.

#### IssueController.php

- The first method works but then my task id "null". All records are inserted from all fields.
- The second method only adds the data of 1 field but it adds the correct id.

```
public function store(Request $request, Issue $issue, Task $task)
 {
    ## First method
    // foreach($request->issueInfo as $key => $value) {
    //     Issue::create($value);
    // }
    ## Second method
    foreach ($request->issueInfo as $key => $name) {
        dd($name);
        $names[] = [
            'task_id'    => $task->id,
            'issue_name' => $name,
            'issue_time' => $name,
            'issue_date' => $name,
            'issue_type' => $name,
        ];
    }
    Issue::insert($names);
    return back();
}
```

#### web.php

```
Route::post('/tasks/{task}/issues',    'IssueController@store');
```

#### show.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var i = 1;
        $('.addmore').click(function(){
            i++;
            $('#dynamicFields').append('<div class="form-group"><label for="issue_name">Issue Name</label><select class="form-control" name="issueInfo['+i+'][issue_name]"><option></option><option value="Error">Error</option><option value="Grammer">Grammer</option><option value="Undefined">Undefined</option><option value="Typpo">Typpo</option><option value="No errors">No errors</option></select></div><div class="form-group"><label for="issue_date" class="label">Issue Date</label><input class="form-control" type="date" name="issueInfo['+i+'][issue_date]"></div><div class="form-group"><label for="issue_time" class="label">Issue Time</label><input class="form-control" type="time" name="issueInfo['+i+'][issue_time]" ></div><div class="form-group"><label for="issue_type" class="label">Issue Type</label><select class="form-control" name="issueInfo['+i+'][issue_type]"><option></option><option value="False45">False45</option><option value="False104">False104</option></select></div><div class="form-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-field">Remove</button></div>');
            });
        // Removing fields
        $('#dynamicFields').on('click', '.remove-field', function(){
            $(this).parents('div').remove(); i--;
        })
    });
</script>
<div class="form-group"><label for="issue_name">Name</label></div>
<head>Testing the creation of multiple fields</head>
<form action="/tasks/{{$task->id}}/issues" method="post" >
    @csrf
    <div id="dynamicFields">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="issue_name">Issue Name</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="issueInfo[0][issue_name]">
                <option></option>
                <option value="Error">Error</option>
                <option value="Grammer">Grammer</option>
                <option value="Undefined">Undefined</option>
                <option value="Typpo">Typpo</option>
                <option value="No errors">No errors</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="issue_date" class="label">Issue Date</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="date" name="issueInfo[0][issue_date]" value="{{old('issue_date')}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="issue_time" class="label">Issue Time</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="time" name="issueInfo[0][issue_time]" value="{{old('issue_time')}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="issue_type" class="label">Issue Type</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="issueInfo[0][issue_type]">
                <option></option>
                <option value="False45">False45</option>
                <option value="False104">False104</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary addmore" value="+" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">New Location</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
@endsection
```

Output when I do dd($names) in my controller

```
                array:1 [▼
          0 => array:5 [▼
            "task_id" => 1
            "issue_name" => array:4 [▼
              "issue_name" => "Error"
              "issue_date" => null
              "issue_time" => null
              "issue_type" => null
            ]
            "issue_time" => array:4 [▼
              "issue_name" => "Error"
              "issue_date" => null
              "issue_time" => null
              "issue_type" => null
            ]
            "issue_date" => array:4 [▶]
            "issue_type" => array:4 [▶]
          ]
        ]
```

[Here you can find a link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kLjme45z/5/)

Comment: what's wrong with your code?

Comment: Can you show the route definition please?

Comment: @GiacomoM I can't send all my records to the database. In my controller, I have to send the generated array to the database. I have a problem sending all the data. The 1 all data is sent but my task_id is null. In the second method, I tried the correct id is added but all other fields are then null instead of the given values.

Comment: @Bryan I have send the route

Comment: I just noticed then when you press remove. All fields disappear, is this suppose to happen?

Comment: @Nemo This is something I will try to solve.

Comment: it seems the parameters of the route and of the store function are different

Comment: @GiacomoM I changed it. But it didn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: check for the `task` object in the function. If id is null probably the task object is null.

Comment: @GiacomoM I dd my data of the array names. I got then for arrays for each field. It seems there is something going wrong. Could you help me with this?

Comment: "something going wrong" does not mean anything. We can not help you if you do not do some research to explain better what is going on

Comment: @GiacomoM The foreach loop should run through the array containing all the data from the fields (name, type, date and time). My loop runs through this field names but not through the data ask you can see in dd($names). What do I need to change on my loop it runs trough the values and insert them in the database.

Comment: `$task->id` is null but you did not write what $task is yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the following. I adapted your code a bit in the fiddle. Instead of pushing everything in the same array, store every element in a separate array. In the fiddle, you find the adapt code. In your controller, you should do the following. You should also remove Issue $issue because you are not using it.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u85act9w/)

```
 public function store(Request $request, Task $task)
    {
        //


        foreach ($request->issue_name as $index  => $name) {

            $task->issues()->create([
                'issue_name' => $name,
                'issue_time' => $request->issue_time[$index],
                'issue_date' => $request->issue_date[$index],
                'issue_type' => $request->issue_type[$index]
            ]);

        }


        return back();
    }
```

To solve your problem with the remove button. Add to your class row for example "remove-this-field". And adapt your javascript code for the removal of the fields to:

```
$('#dynamicFields').on('click', '.remove-fields', function(){
   $('.remov-this-field').remove(); i--;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use built-in Eloquent methods to your advantage.  First, define relationships:

```php
class Task
{
    public function issues()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Issues::class);
    }
{

class Issue
{
    public function task()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
    }
{
```

Next, write a good helper method.  Note the `create()` method already takes an array input, so you don't have to `foreach` through all the array keys:

```php
class Task
{
    ...

    public function addIssue($issue)
    {
        return $this->issues()->create($issue);
    }
}
```

Controller logic can be simplified, and this is a good opportunity to do some server-side validation:

```php
public function store(Request $request, Task $task)
{
    $attributes = request()->validate([
        // issue validation rules here
    ]);

    $task->addIssue($attributes);

    return back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding hidden field to your form where you should set value of that field to task_id which then will be passed to Controller when you submit form.
I think after that your First method should work properly.